# How to change SmartGit's licensing option after 30 days of commercial use on ubuntu?

Tags: git, smartgit

while installing smartgit 3.0.4 I checked the commercial licensing option, because I was just clicking "next" button : ) (30 day trial and then you have to buy it). Now today is my 31st day of using SG and I can't change my licensing options (reinstalling smartgit doesn't help) and I'm not able to use SG anymore without paying (I'm not using it for commercial purposes). Do you know how to fix it?

I don't have these files on my ubuntu: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation.html?page=installation

Answer (score 334, accepted):

I went on the internet and I found this:

To alter the license. First, go to

Windows: `%APPDATA%\syntevo\SmartGit&lt;main-smartgit-version>`

Windows portable: `SmartGit\.settings\preferences.yml`

OS X: `~/Library/Preferences/SmartGit/<main-smartgit-version>`

Unix/Linux: `~/.smartgit/<main-smartgit-version>`

and remove the file `settings.xml`.

If you have updated many times, you may need to remove the `updates` folder as well.

It helped me on Windows, hope it helps you on other systems as well.

Comment: I could not find settings.xml file and removing the whole folder worked as well. rm -rf ~/.smartgit/

Comment: quickest way in linux.  rm -rf ~/.smartgit

Comment: Can you please mention where to enter the command for windows..?

Comment: @Parthiban M `rm -rf ~/.smartgit/` doesn't work on windows, only on unix systems.

Comment: It can be in the following directory. C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\syntevo

Comment: If you want just to change license, do not remove settings.xml. Switch off SmartGIT, rename license file located in SmartGIT's settings folder to license-bkp and start SmartGit. It will ask for new license file.

Comment: \AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit\

Comment: Well it works but it deletes the settings as well. Not a good solution IMHO.

Comment: If you want to keep the rest of your settings and just reset the license, look for the 'listx' key and just delete that object. Of course only do this if you have accidentally selected commercial and you are genuinely a personal user

Comment: Hey ! this solution is not working in Mac , I am not able to find Smartgit folder in Library/Preferecnes , I am smartgit-macosx-17_0_1.dmg

Comment: I confirm this works on Windows just the path given here misses the roaming part - %APPDATA%\roaming\syntevo\SmartGit\<main-smartgit-version>

Comment: I know we usually don't do this in stackoverflow, but I just wanted to say thanks. May the ancient Gods bless you.

Comment: The `~/.smartgit/` directory no longer exists in Linux. See this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222048/732673

Comment: Following @user3265561 's comment, the listx key is now found in preferences.yml from Version 19

Comment: Have to delete `preferences.yml` now

Comment: Also that is required to remove firstUsedKey from preferences. Moreover, if you see only commercial license option, but you are fairly non-commercial one delete "license" file too. Checked on Win portable version

Answer (score 48):

Starting from version 19.1 they have renamed filenames:

```
➜ SmartGit grep -rl 'listx' ./19.1
./19.1/preferences.yml
./19.1/.backup/preferences.yml
```

It is possible to delete them to reset the license setting.

Comment: I had to delete my license files in that same directory too.

Answer (score 36):

For **version 19.1 and above** goto specified directory and **delete** these mentioned files:

1. `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit\20.1<smart-git-version>`

   - **preferences.yml**
   - **license file**
2. `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit\20.1\.backup`

   - **preferences.yml**

For the **previous version** goto specified directory and **delete** mentioned file:

1. `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit\17<smart-git-version>`

   - **setting.xml**

Answer (score 31):

I use linux and the answers did not help me.
I had to erase the folder `~/.config/smartgit` to make it work again. This is what the [documentation is saying](http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/Installation+and+Files#InstallationandFiles-DefaultLocationofSmartGit%27sSettingsDirectorysettings-dir.default-location)

> Default Location of SmartGit's Settings Directory
> **Windows**
>   %APPDATA%\syntevo\SmartGit\ (%APPDATA% is the
>   path defined in the environment variable APPDATA) 
> **Mac OS**
>   ~/Library/Preferences/SmartGit/ (the Finder
>   might not show the ~/Libraries directory by default, but you can
>   invoke open ~/Library from a terminal) 
> **Linux/Unix**
>   ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/smartgit/ (if the
>   environment variable XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not defined, ~/.config is used
>   instead)

Comment: Thanks, in fedora i ended up doing this.

Comment: Junio's answer is a less invasive way of doing this.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

## Since version 22.1 non-commercial license is available upon request only

[Syntevo's blog from 19 October 2022](https://www.syntevo.com/blog/?p=5363) explains that licensing options have been changed with version 22.1. Non-commercial license is only available for:

1. open-source developers,
2. students and employees of (select) educational institutions, and
3. charitable non-governmental organizations,
4. hobby users (requires 23.1 preview).

Any of these have [conditions that need to be fulfilled](https://www.syntevo.com/register-non-commercial/), before a non-commercial license can be issued, or have some restrictions. For example, a hobby license restricts your use to repositories "where you are the only author/committer or which are open source".

Comment: Hobby license is available again since 23.1 (preview 6). You can request a license here: https://www.syntevo.com/register-non-commercial/#hobby

Comment: Thanks, @CrouZ, I accepted your edit and added some more info on hobby license.

Answer (score 17):

My own solution on Linux (under `~/.config/smartgit/19.1`) is to comment or remove line `listx` from `preferences.yml` file and reopen program.

Deleting the all folders will make you reconfigure everything (useless).

Answer (score 10):

Had v22 commercial. This helped me: remove C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\syntevo
and use 21 version from https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download/archive/

Answer (score 8):

**For 19.1 above on Linux,**

Close the App or any window of Smartgit

Go to:

> /home/[USERNAME]/.config/smartgit/[CURRENT OR LAST VERSION]

open the file:

> preferences.yml

Search for:

> "listx: {"
> in this file

You will find something like this:

> listx: {ePP: 1607503071922, eUT: -9223377036854775808, nRT: -9223377036854775808,
> eV: '20.1', uid: emobf7q63s83}

So now all you need is delete the string inside the {} So it will be like this:

> listx: {}

Now save the file and start Smartgit. You will have all repositories and other preferences and you will be asked for set the type of license.

Answer (score 7):

it would be helpful to know if you use linux or windows. in linux the settings are located in
~/.smartgit/3. You could try to remove this folder. Imho this is also worth a try in Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solutions for MAC PC:

Open terminal and type following command to show hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

after that go to current user folder using finder, then you can see the **Library** folder in it which is hidden type

suppose in my case the username is 'Delta' so the folder path is:

```
OS X: ~Delta/Library/Preferences/SmartGit/<main-smartgit-version>
```

Remove settings file and change option to Non Commercial..

Comment: plus 1 for specifying that its needed Library of specific user

Answer (score 4):

I also raced through the first install on ubuntu and selected the default 30 day trial version instead of the non-commercial version.

There is a blog on the syntevo site that [addresses this issue](http://blog.syntevo.net/2012/11/27/1354013721080.html).

After unpacking the tar file I had a dir called smartgithg-4_0_3. I moved this folder to my home directory and renamed it smartgit. After running ./bin/smartgithg.sh, another folder was created called .smartgit (note the . prefix).

I simply deleted the .smartgit folder (the dir tree with all the .xml files) and ran the ,/bin/smarthg.sh script again. The whole install process is repeated. Select the non commercial option when it appears.

Answer (score 4):

Working fine for windows by navigating to %APPDATA%\syntevo\SmartGit\ and delete all settings.xml, then open the installed software

Answer (score 4):

on Mac:

- First goto `~/Library/Preferences/SmartGit/19.1`
- Second goto `preferences.yml` file and just comment `listx` line
- Third open smart git

Answer (score 3):

Smartgit **is not available for free usage** after 22.1 update.

For continue to using smartgit freely follow these steps:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/smartgit
sudo apt-get remove smartgit
```

Now we got rid of old version;

Download older and free version of Smartgit from link below
https://www.syntevo.com/downloads/smartgit/archive/smartgit-20_2_6.deb

Install and done!

Comment: Unfortunately there's a new popup message that says "This outdated SmartGit version can't be evaluated any more". And there's no other option available. I had tried all options under Linux system. Maybe it's time to buy a license or find another free git client.

Answer (score 2):

OSX

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences/SmartGit/
sed -i '' '/listx/d' ./*/preferences.yml
rm */license
```

Windows portable path to `preferences.yml`:

```
SmartGit\.settings\preferences.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

new 2021 hack for Mac:

- First goto ~/Library/Preferences/SmartGit
- Second delete whatever version do you have i have deleted the whole
  20.1 version folder
- Third open smart git

Answer (score 1):

just delete the settings.xml and try againn to setup smartgitHg

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: you can find settings.xml here  AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit\6\settings.xml

Answer (score 1):

Newest versions of SmartGit contain settings under installation folder.
So to reset trial go to the install folder, ex:

```
C:\Program Files\SmartGit
```

and remove(rename) the `.settings` directory

Comment: This is wrong. The `.settings` directory is in your home directory, except of when using the portable bundle.

Answer (score 1):

### For Ubuntu 22.04 and SmartGit 19.1:

**To remove the preferences.yml file in SmartGit on Ubuntu 22.04 with version 19.1, follow these steps:**

1. Open File Manager:

   - Launch your file manager.
2. Show Hidden Files:

   - Press **Ctrl + H** to reveal hidden files and folders. This step is necessary as the configuration files are often hidden.
3. Navigate to SmartGit Configuration Directory:

   - Go to ~/.config/smartgit/19.1 in the file manager.
   - This is where SmartGit stores its configuration files for version 19.1.
4. Remove preferences.yml:

   - Once inside the 19.1 folder, locate the preferences.yml file.
   - Right-click on preferences.yml and select "Delete" or "Move to Trash".
   - Alternatively, you can remove it via the terminal with:

> rm ~/.config/smartgit/19.1/preferences.yml

Answer (score 0):

I have been using windows for the last 13 years. I found this solution to be truly working for me. I recommend you to follow these steps:

- let's start by deleting this folder 
  `C:\Users\Your-name\AppData\Roaming\syntevo`
- Completely uninstall smart git from the control panel, uninstall programs.
- Again re-install the smart git and change the default position of installing directory.
- While configuring smart git, make sure that the non-commercial option is selected that will help you to use the latest as well as a free version for lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the entire Config folder but preserved the files **repositories.yml  repository-cache  repository-grouping.yml**. after running SmartGit, it created the config folder (i think it used the config from an older build (to save things like my git credentials)), then i copied back my three files and i had all my repositories which is the most important info i needed.

Answer (score 0):

For mac users:
in new version there is no setting.xml, alternate way is to

**navigate to SmartGit preferences folder using terminal**

```
cd /Library/Preferences/SmartGit/
```

use `ls` command to see list of folders .. simply delete SmartGit version folder you find using command `rm -r <main-smartgit-version>` and reopen the SmartGit app. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Just use their latest Preview version

### and you are good to go

Previously they wanted you to use just latest stable version now they want you to use latest unstable preview version if you dont want to pay.

Today is 22 June 2023 and I have installed **SmartGit 23.1 Preview 6** as they have mentioned here https://www.syntevo.com/register-non-commercial/#hobby

**TLDR;** 
you can also apply for a personal free licence if you want to use stable version, obviously you dont want to do your project critical sstuff on preview version but for me preview works just fine because I mostly use command line and use smartgit just to view things on GUI I dont make commit or merge using this software I trust command line and I belive just viewing my project in preview version can not harm my project.

Comment: As a person that never pay for anything, today i installed the unstable preview version unwillingly like a dog.

Answer (score 0):

**2023**, On the new version of the MAC OS, remove the settings in the following path:

To reset the trial on macOS, you can simply delete the `~/Library/Application Support/SmartGit/preferences.yml` file. When you start SmartGit again, it will prompt you to enter your license information. You can choose the "Non-Commercial" option to continue using SmartGit for free