# How to switch with SmartGit to non commercial version on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, smartgit

I use Ubuntu 20.04. After 30 days of using SmartGit, it wants to change to commercial version. I use it for personal purposes.

I tried this:
[How to change SmartGit's licensing option after 30 days of commercial use on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972289/how-to-change-smartgits-licensing-option-after-30-days-of-commercial-use-on-ubu)

and this:
https://www.syntevo.com/blog/?p=3669

but couldn't find such folders and files.

I also uninstalled and reinstalled it three times with these commands:

sudo apt remove smartgit

sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove

and

sudo apt install smartgit

but nothing changed.

So can anyone know a way how to change to non commercial version of SmartGit on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: I'm very disappointed about the -1 rating, since after a long exhausing journey of finding the answer I decided to post the question on Stack Overflow. The question is clear and has the neccessary details . What's more there is a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972289/how-to-change-smartgits-licensing-option-after-30-days-of-commercial-use-on-ubu) with high rating, but unfortunately it is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Only applying "Delete the config files of SmartGit" part was enough for me.

So:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/smartgit
```

Then run smartgit and it asks for licensing options again like the first install.

Yes the other options for smartgit are lost removing the folder completely so a fine tuning may be done to this approach if needed.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I found the solution!

With the help of this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/244754/how-to-completely-remove-application

So the process is

1. Remove SmartGit

sudo apt remove smartgit

sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove

2. Delete the config files of SmartGit

Navigate to the home directory,

Ctrl + H to show the hidden folders,

in the .config folder

delete the smartgit folder.

3. Install SmartGit

sudo apt install smartgit

4. Choose the free non-commercial option

Be careful. Choose not the default option but

the free non-commercial option.

Comment: "Your evaluation has already expired". Clearly, this scenario does not remove everything.

Answer (score 0):

Installing an older version worked for me.

The version I had was 22.1.4

I installed 21.1.7 and it asked for the new license options and I could select the free option.

https://www.syntevo.com/downloads/smartgit/smartgit-linux-21_1_7.tar.gz

Comment: Now, old versions show the message "Download latest version, this version will expire at July, 7"

Comment: Indeed. And uninstalling and reinstalling it, even after manually removing the config files, does not reset the trial either